# Javascript Object literal

Tags: javascript, object

Here is my object literal:

```
var obj = {key1: value1};
```

How can I add:

```
{key1: value1,value2,value3}
```

to the object?

Answer (score 4):

```
var obj = {key1: [value1, value2, value3]};
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're declaring it with the values use an array with the object literal.

```
var obj = {key1: [value1, value2, value3]}
```

If you already declared the values, still use an array, but just set the property.

```
obj.key1 = [value1, value2, value3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should modify your object at the specified key to have an array instead of a simple value:

```
obj.key1 = [ obj.key1, 'value2', 'value3' ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var obj = {"key": "val1"};
obj.key=[obj.key, "val2", "val3"]
```